# Send binary data as parameter to a method in Web Service?

Tags: c#, post, visual-c++-6, wininet, windows-2003-webserver

In server side (C#.NET,Windows 2003) I have a web service with a method and in client side (Visual C++ v6, WinINet, POST) I want to call that method and pass binary data as a parameter to it.
when I send Binary data an error rise and when I send ASCII data it called successful. 
How can I send binary data as parameter of a method?

Answer (score 2):

To send binary data to a web method you can base64 encode it and then decode it in the web service.  If your variable is a byte array called data then you would do the following.

In C++ you need to create a base64 header and cpp file. The following example is from http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/common/base64.html

**base64.h**

```
#include <string>

std::string base64_encode(unsigned char const* , unsigned int len);
std::string base64_decode(std::string const& s);
```

**base64.cpp**

```
#include "base64.h"
#include <iostream>

static const std::string base64_chars = 
             "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
             "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
             "0123456789+/";


static inline bool is_base64(unsigned char c) {
  return (isalnum(c) || (c == '+') || (c == '/'));
}

std::string base64_encode(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len) {
  std::string ret;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  unsigned char char_array_3[3];
  unsigned char char_array_4[4];

  while (in_len--) {
    char_array_3[i++] = *(bytes_to_encode++);
    if (i == 3) {
      char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
      char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
      char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
      char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

      for(i = 0; (i <4) ; i++)
        ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[i]];
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  if (i)
  {
    for(j = i; j < 3; j++)
      char_array_3[j] = '\0';

    char_array_4[0] = (char_array_3[0] & 0xfc) >> 2;
    char_array_4[1] = ((char_array_3[0] & 0x03) << 4) + ((char_array_3[1] & 0xf0) >> 4);
    char_array_4[2] = ((char_array_3[1] & 0x0f) << 2) + ((char_array_3[2] & 0xc0) >> 6);
    char_array_4[3] = char_array_3[2] & 0x3f;

    for (j = 0; (j < i + 1); j++)
      ret += base64_chars[char_array_4[j]];

    while((i++ < 3))
      ret += '=';

  }

  return ret;

}

std::string base64_decode(std::string const& encoded_string) {
  int in_len = encoded_string.size();
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  int in_ = 0;
  unsigned char char_array_4[4], char_array_3[3];
  std::string ret;

  while (in_len-- && ( encoded_string[in_] != '=') && is_base64(encoded_string[in_])) {
    char_array_4[i++] = encoded_string[in_]; in_++;
    if (i ==4) {
      for (i = 0; i <4; i++)
        char_array_4[i] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[i]);

      char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
      char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
      char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

      for (i = 0; (i < 3); i++)
        ret += char_array_3[i];
      i = 0;
    }
  }

  if (i) {
    for (j = i; j <4; j++)
      char_array_4[j] = 0;

    for (j = 0; j <4; j++)
      char_array_4[j] = base64_chars.find(char_array_4[j]);

    char_array_3[0] = (char_array_4[0] << 2) + ((char_array_4[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
    char_array_3[1] = ((char_array_4[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
    char_array_3[2] = ((char_array_4[2] & 0x3) << 6) + char_array_4[3];

    for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); j++) ret += char_array_3[j];
  }

  return ret;
}
```

After you have your base64 implementation you can create the string to pass.

```
std::string encoded = base64_encode(data, sizeof(data));
```

You have to be mindful however of the fact that your data will expand by encoding it to Base64 so your uploads will take longer as the data will be larger.  It will be approximately 37% larger (see the MIME section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

To decode the data on the other end you would simply do the following.

```
byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(yourParameterName);
```